# How we can get user information like os, browser in shopping cart using sessions?

Tags: php

Can anyone suggest me how we can store the end user information like what OS he/she will use and what browser he/she is using and in which page he/she is in? I thought it would be better to use sessions to get this type of information but exactly don't know how to do that :(. I am new to PHP can anyone suggest me how to it. Great thanks for your help..

Comment: the user agent can contain the browser and os, but will not always.  THere are so many questions on how to get the os/browser/useragent in php, and then many questions on how to store data across requests in php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**Sessions**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php) are used for storing temporary information in per-user basis, they're not offering any kind of client information.

You are looking in functions as [**get_browser**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php), along with the server information coming with `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']`.

This is not *100%* reliable though, because `HTTP_` server information are not reliable.